# Two polynomials $f,g \in K[x,y]$ ring. Prove that $K[x,y]/(f,g)$ is finite dimensional vector space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Let $f,g \in K[x,y]$ be polynomials with no common factor. Prove that $K[x,y]/(f,g)$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

I know there are non-zero (this word is correct?) $r(x)$ and $s(x)$  in the ideal $(f,g)$. And i think that the quotient $K[x,y]/(r(x),s(y))$ might have finite dimension; but I truly don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Is your $f$ a function of $x$ and $g$ a function of $y$? And what do you mean by "no constant common factor"?

Comment: No, they are polynomials in x and y, f(x,y) and g(x,y). And by this i mean that their common factor must not be a constant. In the original text was "Polinômios sem fator comum não constante ".

Comment: I try to understand, how do you get separated $r(x) = 0$ and $s(y) = 0$ from $f(x,y) = 0$ and $g(x,y) = 0$ ?

Comment: If you do have $r(x),s(y)$, it is easy to show. However if $f,g$ are as you stated, I am not sure. For example, $f=x^3y^3, g=x^4y^2$ satisfy your condition, but $K[x,y]/(f,g)$ is not finite dimensional, since all $x^n, y^m$ are in it.

Comment: It seems to me that they might mean: with no non-constant common factor. In other words, the only element dividing both $f$ and $g$ is a [any] constant. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Remy yes, that's a correct interpretation.

Comment: @user1952009 i truly don't get what you said. r(x) $\in$ K[x,y] and s(y) too.

Comment: Qiaochu answered to my question : you get $s(x)$ (and then $r(y)$) from $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ by seing them as elements of $K[x](y)$ and by the pgcd law

Answer (score 8):

Here's a complete proof. First, regard $f$ and $g$ as elements of $K(x)[y]$. This is a PID, so there exist $a, b \in K(x)[y]$ such that $af + bg = 1$. Clearing denominators, we conclude that there is some polynomial in $(f, g)$ of the form $r(x)$. Similarly, by regarding $f$ and $g$ as elements of $K(y)[x]$, we conclude that there is some polynomial in $(f, g)$ of the form $s(y)$. Now Mohan's argument shows that $K[x, y]/(f, g)$ is finite-dimensional because it is a quotient of $K[x, y]/(r, s)$, which has dimension $\deg r \deg s$.

Geometrically, $K[x, y]/(f, g)$ is the ring of functions on the scheme-theoretic intersection of the curves cut out by $f$ and $g$ in the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$, which (as long as $F$ and $g$ have no common factors) we expect to be a finite set of possibly "fat" points (e.g. $K[x, y]/(f, g)$ could have nilpotents; take, for example, $f = y - x^2, g = y + x^2$). The fact that $(f, g)$ contains $r(x), s(y)$ reflects (up to some "fat") the fact that these points only take finitely many $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

If $r(x),s(y)$ are non-constant polynomials, then it is easy to show that $k[x,y]/(r,s)$ has finite dimension. Since $k[x]/r(x)$ has dimension $\deg r(x)$ and $k[x]/(r(x)[y]/s(y)$ has a basis with dimension $\deg s(y)$ over $k[x]/r(x)$, we have $\dim k[x,y]/(r(x),s(y))=\deg r(x)\deg s(y)$, we have what we need.

Comment: Explicitly, if $\deg r = a$ and $\deg s = b$, a basis for $k[x,y]/(r,s)$ is given by the monomials $x^i y^j$ for $i \in \{0, \ldots, a-1\}$, $j \in \{0, \ldots, b-1\}$.

Comment: But OP said in his comment that $f,g$ are both functions of $x,y$.

Comment: I am confused about the notation $k[x]/r(x)[y]/s(y)$ in your answer. Do you mean $R[y]/s(y)$, where $R=k[x]/r(x)$ ? I think there is a bracket confusion, it should be like $(k[x]/r(x))[y]/s(y)$.